# Error logging sample project

Tags: c#

I need to create a Error logging project from scratch in C#.
I would like to save to a file with several levels, this logging project I am taking as an assignment from which I can learn many things and want to build it as small loggin utility for now.

I saw few loggin project which has singleton pattern and a config file having some entries and also in the consuming application config - some references of logger proj interface are there

can some one please give me an idea as how can I create a new logger
proj from scratch and what is the purpose of having entries in 
config ?

pseudo code for logger project or any link

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're looking for a sample project that *uses* a logging framework or if you're looking for actual logging framework source code. While I'm here, may I suggest log4net as a suitable logging framework? http://logging.apache.org/log4net/

Comment: I am looking for creating my own logger b/c that's the way I will learn

Answer (score 3):

Instead of implementing your own logging mechanism you may want to check whether existing components are an option. For example [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) is a frequently used framework that people use for .NET based projects.

Comment: I am looking for creating my own logger b/c that's the way I will learn

Comment: Maybe you could use log4net to log the errors that occur in your custom logger then?

Comment: I would like to save to a file with several levels i.e critical, normal etc, this logging project I am taking as an assignment from which I can learn many things and want to build it as small loggin utility for now. Thanks for comments

Comment: Perhaps one of the things you'll learn is that you should have saved the time and just used one of the many excellent components already available?

Comment: @Steve - Thanks for comments again, however, I want to learn something - if I use existing components - chances of learning are quite less as compare to developing something from scratch ? what do you say ? that is the reason I want to create a small logger utility.

Answer (score 1):

Also, the Logging Application Block from Microsoft:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569(v=PandP.50).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are several key elements you need to consider before making one from scratch. Just to name what comes to my head :

1. How do you want to log? Do you want to save logs to a file, in a database, to send mails, just to have the logs shown in a console?
2. If you persist the logs, do you want to log everything, forever, or you want a "rolling" X lines to be kept, the rest discarded?
3. Do you want to have several level of logs? For example, you could log some things Info, Warning, Error, Critical Error, etc.
4. Do you want your logging library to support custom formatting for the logs?

As for the question about the config, it's really something you want to do. If you're talking about the app.config files, it allows you to can change the configuration of your application without rebuilding it. It can also provide some default parameters the user can override. By user, I mean another developer using your library.

Comment: I would like to save to a file with several levels, this logging project I am taking as an assignment from which I can learn many things and want to build it as small loggin utility for now. Thanks for comments.